# lost permissions of the printer

Tags: windows-7, printer

I have somehow lost the permissions of the printer even I am the administrator, is there anyway to solve that?

[image]

[image]

Comment: just the creator owner has the rights to manage.

Comment: I have added another  picture from advance and I don t have the permissions. the problem is I am not allowed to print just to manage documents and without the ability th manage the printer I can not print.

Comment: the fisrt picture shows that I have just the rule on managing documents.

Comment: Is the everyone group not allowed to print? Surely if that flag is set you'd still be able to print

Comment: If thats not working you could always take ownership

Comment: the problem has started when I lost the ability to print from my account. so I have edited the permisions but somehow I lost them as administrator and till now I can not print as it shown in the first picture.

Comment: how to take ownership?

Comment: Go into owner. Click on Edit. From there you can take ownership.

Comment: I'll move it to an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take control of your printer.
Right click on the printer and select Properties
Click the Security tab
Click the Advanced button at the bottom of the tab.
Click the Owner tab
Click the Edit button
Select the user you want to take ownership of the object with. Pay attention to the radio button to replace permissions on subcontrainers and objects.
Select Apply.